# pybitcointools - Permission Denied - <urlopen error [Errno 13] Permission denied>

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm trying to recover bitcoin balances and creating new wallets using the library pybitcointools in the google app engine (using webapp2), to create new ballances the request is ok. I do it regularly, however when i'm trying to see the balance i recieve the error

```
 File "D:\Henko\backend\lib\pybitcointools\bci.py", line 114, in 
 history (addr, offset))
 File "D:\Henko\backend\lib\pybitcointools\bci.py", line 21, in 
 make_request raise Exception(p)
 Exception: <urlopen error [Errno 13] Permission denied>
```

The curious thing is, when i put the same code running in a simple file it works. But out of this file in the endpoint that i've created this same code doesn't work!

Someone know how to solve it?

Comment: pybitcointools is no longer maintained, so consider that.

Comment: I know, do you suggest me aother as good as pybitcointools? I looking for one @GAEfan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem configuring the billing account. thx